# When should HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and SignInManager.IsSignedIn(HttpContext.User) be used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

There seems to be some ambiguity about these 2. I use them interchangeably throughout my project and the only reason is because I couldn't figure out when to use one or the other.

What would be the cases where one is true while the other one isn't?

If I were to only use ASP.NET Identity to authenticate users, would one or the other more favourable or it doesn't really matter?

Answer (score 9):

- `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`checks if the current user is
  authenticated(true if the user was authenticated; otherwise, false.). When you set user like this: `HttpContext.User = new
  ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity("SomeAuthType"));` or the request authentication is succeed for any authentication middleware(such as `JwtBearer`) it will be
  true.
- SignInManager is a feature of **aspnet identity** and it checks if the principal has an identity with the *application cookie identity*. If you look at [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L110) you can see : `return principal?.Identities != null && principal.Identities.Any(i => i.AuthenticationType == Options.Cookies.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme);`.

So, if you use aspnet identity and you want to check if user is authenticated by **aspnet identity middleware**(by `app.UseIdentity()`) then use `SignInManager.IsSignedIn`. If you don't use aspnet identity or it is not important how the current user is authenticated then use `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the use-case where you want to use `IsSignedIn` over the `IsAuthenticated`? I just can't see why they've added that in the first place. It's confusing.